# Custom link text wp_get_archive link

Tags: wp-get-archives

Im trying to create custom text for the archive links in my sidebar. Right now it prints it but it comes out as regular text - i'm trying to make the full text output into the link.

so "+ Trip {archive-link}" should be the link text

```
<?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'yearly', 'before' => '<li class="CAPS source-bold"><span class="plus">+</span> Trip ','after' => '</li>', 'format' => 'custom', ) ); ?>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way would be to use the [get_archives_link filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_archives_link/). For example:

```
add_filter ('get_archives_link',
function ($link_html, $url, $text, $format, $before, $after) {
    if ('with_plus' == $format) {
        $link_html = "<li class='CAPS source-bold'><a href='$url'>"
                   . "<span class='plus'>+</span> Trip $text"
                   . '</a></li>';
    }
    return $link_html;
}, 10, 6);
```

Then, in your template:

`<?php wp_get_archives (['type' => 'yearly', 'format' => 'with_plus']) ?>`